# kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying Always Returns True

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have followed as many different examples as I can, most of them in the Apple documentation, but I cannot find out the reason why `kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying` **always** returns a positive on my devices.

**I have initialized and activated the session, yet it still returns positives when my music is paused.**

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    BOOL success = [session setActive: YES error: &activationError];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"%@", activationError); }

    UInt32 otherAudioIsPlaying;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (otherAudioIsPlaying);

    AudioSessionGetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,
                             &propertySize,
                             &otherAudioIsPlaying
                             );

    if (otherAudioIsPlaying) {
        [session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
    } else {
        [session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error: nil];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, managed to fix it by ensuring that an AVAudiosession has been instantiated BEFORE checking the property as follows:

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

Make sure that this occurs before you attempt to check before any other audio is playing and it should work fine :)